# Не могу вывести месяц перед числом после обновления Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Не понимаю, то ли после обновления WP, то ли php версии, даты с форматом

```
wp_date('j F', strtotime($v['date']));
```

Выводятся так: Января 10, а не 10 января. Пробовал менять местами. Не помогает.

Comment: Каклго обновления? Функция появилась в 5.3

Answer (score 2):

Проверил и смена местами работает. Версия wp - 5.3.2

```
echo 'it\' j F format ' . wp_date( 'j F', time() ) . '<br>';
echo 'it\' F j format ' . wp_date( 'F j', time() ) . '<br>';
```

Результат:

```
it' j F format 11 января<br>
it' F j format Январь 11<br>
```